# How do we locate the google_maps_api.xml file

Tags: android, google-maps, api-key

> Get a Google Maps API key
>
> Your application needs an API key to access the Google Maps servers.
>   The type of key you need is a Key for Android applications. The key is
>   free. You can use it with any of your applications that call the
>   Google Maps Android API, and it supports an unlimited number of users.
>
> Choose one of the following ways to get your API key:
>
> ```
> The fast, easy way: Use the link provided in the google_maps_api.xml file that Android Studio created for you:
>     Copy the link provided in the google_maps_api.xml file and paste it into your browser. The link takes you to the Google
> ```
>
> Developers Console and supplies information via URL parameters, thus
>   reducing the manual input required from you.
>           Follow the instructions to create a new project on the console or select an existing project.
>           Create an Android API key for your console project.
>           Copy the resulting API key, go back to Android Studio, and paste the API key into the  element in the google_maps_api.xml
>   file.

I am wondering how do we find that file. Where is it located?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to res > values > google_maps_api.xml here you will find this

Comment: I could not find it. Thanks anyway.

Comment: first you have to create a new android studio project with maps activity(dont choose blank activity when you create project) then you will find this file

Comment: @AkhiPrajapati Same issue here. Does it have to be a _new_ project? What about creating a new maps activity?

Answer (score 6):

In Android Studio 3.0+ , When you sign apk,  release and debug folder is not contain any google_maps_api.xml. i don't know why?

But you just simply put meta data in AndroidManifest.xml

```
   <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
                android:value="@string/API_KEY"/>
```

And properly sign your apk, 
- set package name
- SHA1 key at Google Developer console (Here require **Upload key** and **App signing key by google**)

see my detail answer: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49692374/1978475

Answer (score 5):

For Debug build place key in

`app` > `src` > `debug` > `res` > `values` > `google_maps_api.xml`

and for  Release build place key in

`app` > `src` > `relese` > `res` > `values` > `google_maps_api.xml`

[image]

You can also directly place it directly in strings.xml or in manifest

```
  <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key"/>
```

or

```
 <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="Aiza.._complete_your_key"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Debug key: app > src > debug > res > values > google_maps_api.xml
Release key : app > src > relese > res > values > google_maps_api.xml