# Android app selectively displays Google maps

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm having a strange issue with Google maps. We use them in our app to show some user trips and display those on the map with markers.
The problem is some of the production apps don't display the map, instead showing a blank grey square. Here are some of the considerations and research results:

1. I've been using production app for a few days now and I don't have any problems, maps are displayed, so it's not the maps API key issue. But we have screngrabs of where they are not.
2. Problem is not fixed when app is reinstalled
3. It doesn't depend on the OS version, there is a variety where maps don't work, some are Android 8 and 9. Mine is 9 and it's displayed
4. I thought there could be some connection between crashes and maps, but no, there doesn't appear to be.
5. The worst part is that we can't reproduce the issue as it's only happening on prod builds, it hasn't been noticed on any others ever.

I'm kind of run out of options about where to look. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

So after going away and then spending more time looking into it we found that there are two `.apk`s in Play store when we try to download the prod one: original and derived. And derived one is different SHA1. This post helped me solve the issue, I'd never ever thought it's even possible. 
[Google Maps not working in derived apk (published app)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44599767/1889148)